# QR code AND zbar in Android

Tags: android, camera, qr-code

I have problem with my qrreader.

I need scan only on center screen.

I need square where I have to put qr code before code is scaning.

I try added margin in FrameLayout, but I have blck screen on frame..

It is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        >

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Scanning..."
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/prv" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ScanButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Scan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="turnFlash"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code to scan:

```
 PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
                barcode.setData(data);                

                int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);   

                if (result != 0 && !is_checking) {
                    is_checking = true;
                    String text="";

                    SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                    for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                        text = sym.getData();
                    }


                    if(text.substring(0, 3).matches("htt|www")){
                        previewing = false;
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                        scanText.setText(text);
                        v.vibrate(500);

                        try{
                            if(text.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase("www")){
                                scanText.setText("http://"+scanText.getText().toString());
                            }
                            startWebsite(scanText.getText().toString());
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                    }

                    is_checking = false;
                }
            }
        };
```

I am using Zbar libary.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my app JustScan (can be found at code.google.com as eclipse project), where I used same sample code as you did and modified it as you need.

The idea is to override the method draw(Canvas canvas) of the CameraPreview-class, where you can draw your rectangle for the scan area. To ensure that your overridden method is called you have to call a setWillNotDraw(false) in dhe method surfaceCreated(...).

To crop the preview to your scan area crop the barcode image by using image method setCrop(...) before you pass it to scanImage() in the method onPreviewFrame(...) in the previewCallback function.

Sorry for this very short explanation, but I can't list the complete code here. Hope it helps anyway...

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.